# difference between container and exectuor in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

Please suggest what do we mean by this sentence: `"The application master will start an executor in container".` 
in other word, an executor will run in container.?

I know the definition of container mean we have % resources allocated (cpu,ram,disk) but it still confusing for me this sentence of The application master will start an executor in container

Do we mean an executor will run in container = when that the java virtual machine will be loaded in the Ram ?

to be more clear look this two screen :

[image]

source :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJ0eUZxF80s&t=650s

Thank in advance. i hope you understand my question more clearly than last time

Comment: Container is Yarn and think of it as an allocation of space, executor is Spark process and runs inside of the container.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Spark executor would be running inside the container (as referred in YARN). Application Master would liaise with Node Managers to run the required containers and then Spark executor will run inside these containers.

Please refer below for more details :

https://0x0fff.com/spark-architecture/

Answer (score 0):

Spark Executor runs within a Yarn Container, not across Containers.

A Yarn Container is provided by the YARN Resource Manager on demand - at start of Spark Application of via YARN Dynamic Resource Allocation.

A Yarn Container can have only one Spark Executor, but 1 or indeed more Cores can be assigned to the Executor